# Injecting a JDBC Database connection in a Play for Scala standalone application

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I inject `JDBC Database Connections` in Play for Scala to use in web applications as [explained here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDatabase#obtaining-a-jdbc-connection):

This is the declaration I use:

```
class ScalaControllerInject @Inject()(db: Database) extends Controller {

    // rest of the code...
```

What I need is to inject the JDBC Database Connection in a **standalone** Play for Scala application (i.e. there's no Controller), like so:

```
object Main extends App {

    val db: Database  = // ... get database 
    val conn = db.getConnection()

    // .... rest of the code
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just create one (Postgres example):

```
val dbUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/databaseName?user=username&password=yourpassword"
val database = Databases("org.postgresql.Driver",dbUrl,"testingzzz")
```